# Qooxdoo Android zoom issue

Tags: android, zooming, qooxdoo

I have a web application and I want to also load it on mobile. When it loads, if I pinch to zoom on my iPad, it zooms out with no problems, but if I try on Android, I can zoom until the page is fully loaded and after that I cannot zoom anymore, neither scroll. Zoom bug was solved in version 3.0.0 from what I read on the official web site.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I saw some demos on their website but didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the index.html of your qooxdoo application.

Make sure, you have set `user-scalable=yes` in your meta viewport rule.

Comment: I checked and user-scalable was set to yes